# Multiple SSL certs for one domain - how?

Tags: ssl, https

I'm wanting to build a LAMP stack solution for delivering secure content, but I don't want to be able to know what that content is. I've worked out the file encryption, but I now have the problem of transferring the secure content to the remote browser for viewing. I want to avoid sending an encrypted file like Mega does, I want to use HTTPS with strong SSL instead.

Using a single SSL certificate for the whole domain would let me (the cert owner) decrypt the stream.

I'd like to solve this by having an SSL certificate per-user, which are encrypted server-side by the user's password.

Only problem I have to work out is how to make one domain use more than one SSL certificate somehow. How to do this?

I'm open to using Ngnix but would prefer to use Apache.

Comment: This looks very unfeasible as it is. SSL certificate have to be validated by an authority, and are still very permanent and cannot really be generated "on-the-fly". Maybe someone knows better, but this doesn't sounds right.

Comment: If you are sending unencrypted files over HTTPS from your web server, you as the operator of that server will be able to see the data as well. You don't have to intercept the stream, you can look at the server. If you want to make it impossible for yourself to read the files, you need to have end-to-end-encryption (and that means that the files are sent encrypted and decryption happens at the client application).

Comment: I'm not planning to use SSL certs from a root authority, I plan to setup my own CA, an intermediary CA, and self-sign. The idea is to guarantee security, and I can't really guarantee the NSA hasn't compromised several root/intermediaries by now. I am un-encrypting the files into RAM, and then sending them. I'm making it very difficult for myself to get the unencrypted content, that's the idea.  Can we nevermind the technicalities of the other stuff, how can I use more than one SSL certificate on one domain?

Comment: How is that making it difficult for you? If you have the capability to decrypt the file, then you have the capability. This implies that you have access to the decryption keys, that you need to store them, that you could be hacked and they could be stolen. That you store plain-text in RAM only is immaterial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can probably get much better answers over at crypto.stackexchange.com (and you should really include the whole solution into the discussion, not just focus on the HTTPS detail).

Comment: If you want to not get the CA mechanism involved (so that a malicious CA cannot do man-in-the-middle), you can self-sign your SSL cert (own CA or not) and use key pinning in the clients. No need to change the key for every client or connection.

Comment: My question is how to use more than one SSL certificate with only one domain.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want with a LAMP stack but you have to write your own web server which first identifies the user somehow (by IP address?) before doing the TLS handshake because you ask for a user specific certificate. Existing servers like Apache or nginx assume a static certificate for a server and not a dynamic one which somehow gets associated with the user.

But even if you manage to create such a server it will probably not help to provide the main goal you seem to have, i.e. hiding the served content from the owner of the web server itself. SSL/TLS is end to end encryption which means that the content has to be available on the server first as plain text before it can be encrypted for transport. And that means also that the owner of the server can have access to the content.

The only way you can make sure that the server owner has no access is to encrypt the files with a key only known to sender and recipient but not to the server owner. That's the concept Mega uses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I was looking for.